# Question about Ribet's converse to Herbrand

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I refer to the paper by Ribet where he proves the converse to Herbrand's theorem  ([https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/invent_34.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eribet/Articles/invent_34.pdf)). In the paper, he mentions that Theorem 1.1 is equivalent to Theorem 1.2 using the functoriality of the Artin Symbol. Can somebody please  explain this equivalence in more detail?

Comment: I think this is just the usual translation from the class group side to the unramified extension side of global class field theory. The functoriality formula (11.5 in Tate's article of Cassels-Frohlich) is used in part (c). What part of Theorem 1.2 do you struggle with?

Comment: I am struggling with part (c). For parts (a) and (b), we take $E$ to be the maximal p power extension contained inside the Hilbert class field of $K$. Could you please spell out the details for part (c) using the functoriality formula?

Comment: Almost. There is a surjective map from the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$ to $C(\chi^{1-k})$. Under the reciprocity this gives the extension $E/\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$ with Galois group $\psi: C(\chi^{1-k})\cong H$. Now $\tau\in H$ is $\psi(x)$ for some $x$ in $C(\chi^{1-k})$. For any $\sigma$, the Theorem in CF shows $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} = \psi(\bar \sigma x) = \psi ( \chi^{1-k}(\sigma) x) = \chi^{1-k}(\sigma) \cdot \psi(x)$ since we know how the Galois group acts on the class group by definition of $C(\chi^{1-k})$.